# Why powershell and cmd.exe use the git config file is in C:\c\Users\xxx\.gitconfig?

Tags: windows, git

I have installed git on my windows pc, when I run `git config --global` using powershell or cmd.exe, it's writing to this file `C:\c\Users\xxx\.gitconfig`.

While when I run the git config command in git-bash, it's operating this file:
`C:\Users\xxx\.gitconfig`

Where the `c\` folder coming from?? I don't get it.

How can I tell powershell and cmd.exe use the same file as git-bash??

Comment: Consider [filing an issue](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/) but be sure to specify your Git for Windows version, OS version and the result of running the `set` command in `cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the issue: I had installed Cygwin before, and it had set the `HOME` environment variable on my PC to `c\Users\xxx`. That’s why PowerShell and cmd.exe were locating the file in that folder.